# JQuery working with two lists and button controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two lists of divs that I wish to navigate through with buttons (up, down, left, right). Each time a button is pressed, the result div in my html gets replaced with the "current" div. As such, I have a horizontal and vertical list. The horizontal navigation works perfectly but when I click my down button, my vertical list returns an index of -1 and nothing is displayed. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//this creates the lists of divs
var $list = $(".slides > div");
var $vlist = $(".yslides > div");

//this initializes the index tracking values horizontal
//and vertical
var $hcurrent = 0;
var $vcurrent = 0;

//this is because I kept getting console undefined errors
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
    window.console = {
        log: function () {}
    };
}

/*
R I G H T   B U T T O N
*/

$("#right").click(function(){
    //this removes the current indexed div
    //and sets the the current index as next
    var $next = $list.filter(".current").removeClass('current').next();

    //this is for wrap around
    //if this hits the max value of horizontal indexes it wraps around
    if(!$next.length){
        $next = $list.first()
    }

    //this adds the next div
    $next.addClass('current');

    //this outputs the div to the "result" div
    $("#result").html('').append($next.clone());

    //this tracks and updates the horizontal index
    $hcurrent  = $list.index($(".current"));

    //this is for the undefined error, again
    if (typeof console == "undefined") {
        window.console = {
            log: function () {}
        };
    }

    //this is the console out put, tracks the current horizontal index, 
    horizontal list length(number of indexes, active flag
    //current veritical idex, and vertical list length
    console.log("Right Pressed. " , "hc: ",$hcurrent, "hi: ",$list.length, 
     $active, "vc: ", $vcurrent,"vi: ",$vlist.length);
});

/*
L E F T  B U T T O N
*/

$("#left").click(function(){

    //this removes the current indexed div
    //and sets the the current index as the Previous element
    var $next = $list.filter(".current").removeClass('current').prev();

    //this adds the previous class to $next
    $next.addClass('current');

    //this appends the previous index/class to result 
    $("#result").html('').append($next.clone());

    //tracks current horizontal index
    $hcurrent  = $list.index($(".current"));

    //active flag controls
    if (($hcurrent != 0) && ($hcurrent % 2 == 0) ){
        $active = true;
    }
    else{
        $active = false;
    }

    //undefined console error checking
    if (typeof console == "undefined") {
        window.console = {
            log: function () {}
        };
    }

    console.log("Left Pressed. " , "hc: ",$hcurrent, "hi: ",$list.length, $active, "vc: ", $vcurrent,"vi: ",$vlist.length);    
});

/*
D O W N   B U T T O N
*/

$("#down").click(function(){

    //this removes the current indexed div
    //and sets the the current index as the Previous element
    var $next = $vlist.filter(".current").removeClass('current').next();

    //this adds the previous class to $next
    $next.addClass('current');
     alert("added the class");
    //this appends the previous index/class to result 
    $("#result").html('').append($next.clone());

    //tracks current horizontal index
    $hcurrent  = $list.index($(".current"));

    //active flag controls
    if (($hcurrent != 0) && ($hcurrent % 2 == 0) ){
        $active = true;
    }
    else{
        $active = false;
    }

    //undefined console error checking
    if (typeof console == "undefined") {
        window.console = {
            log: function () {}
        };
    }

    console.log("Left Pressed. " , "hc: ",$hcurrent, "hi: ",$list.length, $active, "vc: ", $vcurrent,"vi: ",$vlist.length);    
});
});
```

Comment: Perhaps there is no vlist next to left and right divs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. left and right are for horizontal navigation and down is for vertical. They use $list, and up and down are supposed use $vlist.

Comment: Typically in positional adjustments in a grid setting the adjustments are: left = -1, right = +1, up = -rowLength, down = +rowLength.  Such that if you are in say a 3 x 3 grid and are in position 2 (row 1, col 3), if you hit down, your new position is 2 +3 for 5 or (row 2, col 3).

Comment: But these are indexed in a list using jQuery prev() and next(). They are not supposed to fall below 0.

Comment: If they go below 0 they are supposed to wrap around to the last element as far as I know.